# Twilio C# Attach Cookie to response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, twilio, whatsapp

I have a DeliveryNotice function that gets called by Twilio after a Whatsapp message has been sent. In that function, I want to set a response cookie or a header so that when my user replies to the Whatsapp message, I am able to trace which message it originated from.

I have tried setting the cookies and headers but when the InboundMessage function is called when a User replies, I am unable to see the set cookie and even the set header.

This is my code:

```
[HttpPost("FileDeliveryNotice")]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public ActionResult FileDeliveryNotice([FromForm] WhatsappFileDeliveryNotice Input)
{
    var r = Request;
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("MessageSID", Input.MessageSid);
    Response.Headers.Add("MessageSID", Input.MessageSid);
    return Ok(res);
}

[HttpPost("InboundMessage")]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public ActionResult InboundMessage([FromForm] WhatsappInboundMessage Input)
{
    var r = Request;
    var res = whatsappIMData.Save(Input);
    return Ok(res);
}
```

EDIT:

```
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
var message = MessageResource.Create(
    body: messageText,
    statusCallback: new Uri($"{configuration[SDR_Core.ClassLibrary.Globals.ConfigurationGlobals.Whatsapp_Callback_Url]}Communication/Whatsapp/FileDeliveryNotice"),
    to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber($"whatsapp:+6{Input.NewSendFileDetailsViewModel.MobileNumber}"),
    messagingServiceSid: tcd.TwilioMessagingServiceSID
);
```

Comment: You should be able to do this with Cookies, though they only last 4 hours, so that could be the issue? Here's the documentation on [setting cookies in C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-create-sms-conversations-csharp#using-http-cookies-with-webhooks) that might give you an hint for what's wrong.

Comment: When my user replies immediately, and the twilio webhook calls InboundMessage, the headers do not contain the set headers  and the cookies are empty though. The code sample uses asp.net mvc which supports Session. I am using .net core.

Comment: When does FileDeliveryNotice get called?

Comment: When the message is first sent out. I edited my code to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can only set cookies for Twilio messaging when you are responding to an incoming webhook of a message and not when you send a message with the REST API or receive an asynchronous status callback.

So, really what I mean is that you can only set those cookies on your `InboundMessage` route and that's why you're not seeing this.

The thing is, currently within Twilio there isn't really the idea of what message was being replied to. That's mostly because the API was based on SMS in the first place, which is solely chronological. There is the idea of responding to a message in WhatsApp, but that requires the user to specifically respond to the message and it is not supported in Twilio. So it is best to consider the messages as chronological with WhatsApp too. So you can always look at the last message you sent to see what the person is likely responding to.

Comment: Hi @philnash, thanks for replying. This seems a little vague. Currently my scenario is this. My system sends a template message with a yes or no button. If the recipient clicks on yes, deliver a file that is specific to them.  The part I am stuck on is that I know that I can add parameters to the DeliveryNotice function such as FileId. But how do I pair the recipient response to know which file to send to them?

Comment: The `FileDeliveryNotice` action is only called as a status callback to give you information about the message that you sent. It doesn't really have an effect on the next reply from the user. You can store what the last message that you sent the user was, against their WhatsApp phone number, then when you receive an inbound message, look up that previous message with the phone number again, and then use that information to send them the file.

Comment: I see. I have been going about this the wrong way then. May I know if there is a way to add a incoming webhook url when sending the message or is there any way to put dynamic parameters in the url? It seems like it can only be set on the console at the moment.

Comment: There is no way to do that, no. Like I said, you need to deal with things chronologically.

Comment: Hi @philnash, after some thought, I was hoping you could help me answer a question. If I deal with things chronologically, what happens if I send a message to a recipient at the same time as another user using the same messaging service/number? Am I right to say that only the latest message response will be registered by my InboundMessage function? The message before the latest will still output the response given by the latest message.

Comment: Yes, when dealing with messages chronologically it becomes difficult when there are parallel conversations going on. There are basically 3 options here: 1) you purposely only keep one conversation going at a time, so your don’t send the message from the other user until the first conversation is over or times out. 2) you get the user to send an identifier in the message so you know which message they are responding to, this could work with buttons in WhatsApp. 3) you get another number to send from, making the message dependent on both who sent it and which number they replied to.

Comment: Hi @philnash, thank you for your help. I understand how I should write it out now.